# Pandas: Duplicated column number after column split by comma

Tags: python, pandas

I have a faw data file and I need to split the column index 0 by comma. The dataset has no headers so I had to control index by number. After split, I will need to hash one of the column values before joining them back.

I using the code below to split.

```
Test = pd.concat([df,df[0].str.split(',',expand=True)],axis=1)
```

The column did split successfully but it appended the new columns after the last (which is 29 for my case) as 0,1,2,3,4, etc. Now I have repeated column numbers which I csnt rename properly. If I rename column 0 to 30, 2 columns will be rename.

I have tried using Test.reindex(axis=1) but nothing happens to the column index number.

How do indexed index column correctly?

Comment: kindly provide data, with expected output. [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename new columns, e.g. by [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
Test = pd.concat([df,df[0].str.split(',',expand=True).add_prefix('new')],axis=1)
```

Or for default columns names by range use:

```
Test = pd.concat([df,df[0].str.split(',',expand=True)],axis=1)
Test.columns = np.arange(len(Test.columns))
```